# Dataframe bar plot not consistent x axis with plt.plot

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"segments": [2, 2, 2, 5, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4], "values": [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]})
df.groupby("segments").size().plot(kind="bar")

plt.plot([3, 3], [0, 5])
```

Let's say I have a dataframe with columns segments and values. I want to plot bar graph for frequencies of segments and a line graph on a same axes.

But when I run the code above x axis is not consistent within the graphs. The x values of the line should have been in "3" in the x-axis. (see image below).

What am I suppose to do to fix this issue. (I want to use groupby().size() on dataframes)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

When overlapping graphs with the pandas plotting function, write the code to plot them consecutively. Also, in this case, the x-axis is a categorical variable, so set use_index to false.

```
df.groupby("segments").size().plot(kind="bar")
df.groupby("segments").size().plot(kind="line", use_index=False)
```

[image]